# How can I make texdoc find certain documentation?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, texdoc

(This is a question in relation to something brought up in chat, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=1918860#1918860.)

I'm using [TeX Live 2009 in Ubuntu 11.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/texlive-full) and neither `texdoc pgf` nor `texdoc tikz` opens [the TikZ/PGF manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). Is there a way to make it so that `texdoc` finds the manual?

`locate pgfmanual.pdf` returns:

```
/usr/share/doc/texmf/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf.gz
```

`texdoc -l pgf` returns:

```
1 /usr/share/texmf/doc/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf.gz
2 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/doc/latex/pgf-soroban/pgf-soroban-doc.pdf
```

Comment: Sneaky small font!

Comment: In the default configuration file (`texdoc.cnf`) it is shown how to cope with compressed files.

Comment: What does `texdoc -l pgf` show? I have `pgfmanual.pdf` as entry 1 (of 20) with a full TL2011. Do you have a full installation (i.e. scheme 'full')?

Comment: @JosephWright I've added the output to my question.

Comment: @joseph TL still only have TL 2009. @NN I usually recommend installing the `offcial` TL as well as the Ubuntu one (one just have to make sure that the official TL comes first in the PATH). Then (1) one has an updated LaTeX installation (the best IMO), (2) you can update it yourself using `tlmgr`, Ubuntu removes `tlmgr` and (3) because we still have TL2009 installed, dependencies for editors like `Kile` are still fulfilled.

Comment: @delaif: I fully agree. Also the dependency to Kile is just added by the Ubuntu (or the underlying Debian) package management. I don't think there is any binary dependency between Kile and LaTeX. I would say you can use Kile also without any LaTeX installed as long as you don't try to compile anything, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As egreg suggested in a comment the information on how to deal with compressed documentation is found in the `texdoc.cnf` file. Here's how I get it working:

1. First I had to find the file.

   ```
   $ locate texdoc.cnf
   ```
2. In it I found the following:

   ```
   # If you want to enable support for zipped documentation (see comments in
   # texdoc.tlu), you may want to adapt viewer_* so that it starts a subshell:
   #
   # viewer_pdf = (xpdf %s) &
   #
   # Otherwise, the & will have no effect since the viewing command is followed by
   # some cleanup-commands for temporary files. For the same reason, %s must be the
   # last thing on your command line: (xpdf %s -option) will not work.
   ```
3. Since I don't have xpdf installed and I want robust solution I chose to let `see` choose an appropriate viewer. Thus I added the following line to `~/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` (which was empty to I had create it):

   ```
   viewer_pdf = (see %s) &
   ```
4. Tried the following successfully:

   ```
   $ texdoc pgf
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Put the following into your `texdoc.cnf` file (e.g. under `~/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf`) to automatically unzip the `.pdf.gz` files:

```
zipext_list = gz
unzip_gz    = gzip -d -c
```

This is described (as egreg already pointed out) in the default `texdoc.cnf` file (`/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` in my case).

Comment: I have put the two lines you mention in `~/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` and it still doesn't work. The output I get from `texdoc -f` includes `(*) active /home/nn/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf`.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I can't recreate the issue with my TeXLive 2011 installation. Maybe your version needs different settings, see the main config file, maybe it can help you. You could uncompress the PDF to your `~/texmf/doc/latex/pgf/` directory as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As Evince can open pdf.gz file, I just created a texmf.cnf file in $HOME/texmf/texdoc containing this line:

```
viewer_pdf = (evince %s) &
```

and the command `texdoc pgf` worked(on ubuntu 13.04). Hope that's help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution:
For me, it only worked once I combined @MartinScharrer's and @Ben's approach

```
zipext_list = gz
unzip_gz    = gzip -d -c
viewer_pdf = (evince %s) &
```

I'm using the [Texlive backport](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) on Ubuntu 12.04, if that makes any difference.